# Calculating extrema of a given function on a geometrical region

Tags: mathematical-optimization, homework

I've never used *Mathematica* before. Now I have to figure out, for one of my classes, how to find the max and min of the function $f(x,y)=x^3+2\ xy$ over the triangular region of the plane with vertices $(-4,-1)$ and $(0,3)$ and $(4,-1)$.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Do you know how to express your function in *Mathematica* syntax? In any case, functions of interest to you will be e.g. [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html) and [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html): they take variable ranges expressed as geometrical regions; and [`Triangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Triangle.html) to express your region using its vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was bale to do this using Maximize[x^3+2 x y,{x,y}\[Element]Triangle[{{-4,-1},{0,3},{4,-1}}]]

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you got it working. If you'd like, you can post your solution as a self-answer for future reference: those are encouraged on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer:

```
Maximize[x^3 + 2 x y, {x, y} ∈ Triangle[{{-4, -1}, {0, 3}, {4, -1}}]]

Minimize[x^3 + 2 x y, {x, y} ∈ Triangle[{{-4, -1}, {0, 3}, {4, -1}}]]
```

Comment: This one does not work `Maximize[Cos[y] Sin[x], {x, y} \[Element] 
  Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}, {2 \[Pi], 0}}]]`